# How to split 1 channel audio into 2 channels?

Tags: python, audio, diarization, audio-channels

I have an audio file with two speakers on 1 channel. I would like to separate the audio in 2 channels (one per speaker).

I was thinking of splitting on silences, or more complicated things like [speaker diarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_diarisation) to i.e. to detect different speakers in an audio recording.

How would you do?

Comment: It's not a trivial problem. What about trying some of the open source tools mentioned in the Wikipedia article? If you want to roll your own, you need a solid background of information theory, statistical signal processing etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Seems to be a complicated speech signal processing problem, specified as [blind source seperation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_separation). Traditional methods include PCA/ICA and NMF. Modern method introduces neural network.